# Using CUDA with catkin - can't generate messages

Tags: ros, catkin, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To add cuda support to a catkin package, I'm using `find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)` right after `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)`. This works by itself; however, if I call `generate_messages(...)` in the same CMakeLists.txt, cmake fails with the following error:

`CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:251 (include): include called with wrong number of arguments.  Include only takes one file. Call Stack (most recent call first): Personal/ros_cuda_test/CMakeLists.txt:37 (generate_messages)`

Both `find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)` and `generate_messages(...)` work in isolation, so it isn't a problem with the messages it's trying to generate.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77261/using-cuda-with-catkin---can%27t-generate-messages/) by [Calder](https://answers.ros.org/users/4279/calder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 161 on 2013-09-08

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I appear to have fixed the problem with

`find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)`

`set(config)`

so that the `config` variable used in `generate_messages(...)` gets cleared of anything remaining from finding CUDA. This successfully compiles.

However, I'm hesitant to call this a solution, since I don't know if catkin is expecting a value for `config` (hence why `generate_messages(...)` doesn't clear the variable itself)

---

Originally posted by [Calder](https://answers.ros.org/users/4279/calder/) with karma: 161 on 2013-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-09-08**:
This sounds like it might be worth filing an issue against `message_generation` or `genmsg`, this could probably be fixed there and made more robust to outside interference.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-09-09**:
I a pretty sure that is a bug in genmsg. Even if the code looks like that it tries to deal with it (https://github.com/ros/genmsg/blob/groovy-devel/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake.em#L252) it seems to fail so I have filled a ticket: https://github.com/ros/genmsg/issues/33